# android: Go Back To Main Activity Without Losing It's Data

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making a quiz app for school. I have Activities A, B, C, and D. `Activity` A is the Main `Activity` that has the settings data, including a private `int` variable specifying the time limit in seconds per question. `Activity` B is the list where a user can choose a quiz, where it will take them to `Activity` C to take the actual quiz. When the user finishes the quiz, it will go to `Activity` D showing the score and a button labeled as "Home" to go back to the Main `Activity` (A).

How do I go back from `Activity` D to my Main `Activity` (A) while not restarting the Main `Activity`? I tried the following:

```
case R.id.homeButton:
    Intent backToHomeActivityIntent = new Intent(QuizResultsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    backToHomeActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(backToHomeActivityIntent);
    break;
```

The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` does half of what I want it to do, which as I understand destroys activities B, C, and D. However, the Main `Activity`(A) resets to the default time limit instead of the one that was set from the Settings `Activity` (not specified as one of the letter Activities). I'm thinking that it's starting a new instance of the Main `Activity`. I also tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, and it does keep the saved time limit, but doesn't destroy the other Activities and just brings the Main `Activity` to the top of the `Activity` stack.

What I want to do is go from `Activity` D to `Activity` A while destroying Activities B, C, and D WHILE `Activity` A's settings and set variables are kept in tact from when they were previously changed. How do I achieve this?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bundle to send the data between 2 activity.
Step 1: Add data into the bundle and send it

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key", "value");
        Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Step2: Get data from bundle

```
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String value = bundle.getString("key");
        }
```

I hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But then I read around that Activities are not reliable to contain app settings and that I should use the `SharedPreferences` API instead so the settings persist even after the app is terminated. So I got another API to add to my project for a higher grade! :D I'm still marking this question as correct since it did solve the initial problem for more at first along with me using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer mate. You saved me a lot of hassle :D

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is prevent `ActivityA` from being killed and recreated. TO do that, you need to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the `Intent` you use to go back to `A`:

```
backToHomeActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`
[See more by click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)